# AngularJS :Controllers per row inside ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table of 100 rows. Each row represents a complex object which is an instance of a type . Now there are operations that need to be performed on a row level based on user interaction. 
The operations possible in each object is different for each row and is independent of the state of other objects.
Now my current pattern goes like this. One single controller for entire table.

```
$scope.list = [] // List of instances. Instances which I get by doing new on a factory function
```

Each object maintains its state .Through its instance which has getters,setters,and row level logic.
For a table of 100 objects. I have one controller and 100 instances.(Each for one object)

Now I was thinking whether it makes sense to have row level controllers.
So if there are 100 objects rendered in the table ,there will be 101 controllers.Along with 100 objects.
(100 row level,1 table level)

This will allow me to maintain view related logic for each object in the controller instead of in the factory instance.

Is there any performance considerations that I should know of ? Or is the pattern not good ? I will like to know your feedback on this about using controllers inside ng-repeat?

Comment: What kinds of objects are you making? What kinds of tags in the HTML?

Comment: How does that matter ? Objects are represented in memory.They can have any tags.

Comment: What are you asking here? Performance-related concerns or something else? If it's anything else, like style, I'm afraid the answer is going to be "it depends".

Comment: I am trying to understand the pros and cons of such an implementation.

Comment: Well then, as I said, "it depends".

Answer (score 1):

You are asking whether nesting controllers in an `ng-repeat` Angular structure is a good idea. Specifically, you are asking whether you should have a different controller for each of the 100 "objects" you plan to create in the "loop". The answer, unfortunately, is "it depends". Sometimes it's a good idea, such as when the "objects" you mention are in fact whole pages dynamically included using `ng-include`. In this case, having a controller for every page can be a good thing, especially if each sub-page has a different function. Other times, it's a horrible idea, such as when your `ng-repeat` is on a `<select>` tag and the objects you iterate over are `<option>`s. In this case, a controller for each `<option>` is almost always unnecessary, especially when you have 100. Anything you could do with an inner controller you could do another way, or in the outside controller, with much less work.

As for performance concerns, if you are creating 100 of anything on your website, the `controller`s are probably not your biggest bottleneck.

Comment: Can you elaborate  Anything you could do with a controller you could do another way with much less work. ?

Comment: By the way . Think of it as a table where each row can have multiple input tags . which is linked to a property on the object .There are 100 such objects.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I meant anything you could do *on an `<option>` tag* with a 2nd controller you could do with only 1 controller. I will change it.

Comment: My whole point with this answer, though, is that, unless you are very clear on what you want to use 100 controllers for, `StackOverflow` can't help you. So are you saying you are doing a table with inputs in each `ng-repeat`? You're gonna have to be clearer than that.

Comment: Sorry, but I flagged your question because it was too broad. I suppose I could have gone with unclear, but "too broad" seemed closer.